# What is Arrival Queue?

Tags: data-structures

I'm confused about the meaning of arrival queue, the only thing I know about it was, it follows strict FIFO and that's confusing.Can someone please help me define what arrival queue is?

Comment: is there any context ?

Comment: Sounds like someone is having hard time on university exams.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have a queue in a bank, the first who enters will leave also first.Then the second will follow and so goes on, until the queue becomes empty.was it helpful?